# Python closures and replacing surrounding scope

Tags: python, closures

I know when using Groovy closures, I can change the `delegate` on the closure so function calls made within the closure could be defined externally.

Can I do something similar in Python?

Specifically, if you take the following code:

```
def configure():
  build()

def wrap(function):
  def build():
    print 'build'

  function()

wrap(configure)
```

I'd like it to print 'build' (only making changes to `wrap()`).

Some notes:

I don't want to pass functions into `configure()` since there may be a large number of functions that can be called by `configure()`.

I also don't want to define those globally, because, once again, there may be a large number of functions that can be called by `configure()` and I don't want to pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether or not is a good way to do this is debatable, but here's a solution that doesn't modify the global namespace.

```
def configure():
  build()

def wrap(f):
  import new
  def build():
    print 'build'

  new.function(f.func_code, locals(), f.func_name, f.func_defaults, f.func_closure)()

wrap(configure)
```

I found it at [How to modify the local namespace in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142068/how-to-modify-the-local-namespace-in-python)

Comment: Indeed - this is the exact answer for the question asked. The `new.function`type is also avaliable as `types.FunctionType` - and what it does is make the local variables in `wrap` available as global variables in the newly created function.

Answer (score 3):

This is doable without metaprogramming. Have `configure` take the `build` function as a parameter:

```
def default_build():
    print "default build"

def configure(build_func=None):
    build_func = build_func or default_build
    build_func()

def wrap(func):
    def build():
        print "wrap build"

    func(build)

wrap(configure)
```

This way makes it explicit that the behaviour of the `configure` function can change.

You can fiddle with the namespaces `configure` sees as well to do something more like what I understand Groovy does:

```
def build():
    print "default build"

def configure():
    build()

def wrap(func):
    def _build():
        print "wrap build"

    old_build = func.func_globals['build']
    func.func_globals['build'] = _build
    func()
    func.func_globals['build'] = old_build
```

Comment: Sure, but let's say there's the potential of many functions that may be called. I'd rather not make changes to configure().

Comment: @ReverendGonzo: I edited the answer to add a more direct method. I still think it will lead to confusing code though. If a function's behaviour can be parameterised, I'd just make that fact explicit even if it's laborious.

Comment: @ReverendGonzo: Actually, what I'd probably do is apply OO and make `configure` and `build` methods of a class and change them by subclassing / monkeypatching instances of the class.

Comment: so modifying func_globals is effectively the same as modifying the global namespace. I'm trying to go the class route because I'm trying to have a scriptable DSL that's as simple as possible. I think modifying the global namespace may be the only option, but still digging.

Comment: Maybe you can wrap that with contextmanager and use "with" syntax? But in any case I agree explicit is better than implicit. Bad design is hard to implement in Python ;)

Comment: @ReverendGonzo Hm. I thought `func_globals` is a *copy* of the global namespace, apparently I was wrong. This would indeed make my second solution substantially similar to one in the other answers, with the exception that a) `wrap` and `configure` don't have to have the same global namespace - `wrap` should change whatever enclosing namespace is applicable for `configure`, and b) you can undo the pollution instead of clobbering the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

If you're feeling crazy and awesome, have a look at [this article about dynamic scoping](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/code_blocks.shtml).

Basically, the idea is to modify the bytecode of a function (using the `byteplay` module) and replace all references that are not strictly local-scope with ones that are. To illustrate the basic concept (in Python-pseudocode):

```
code = byteplay.extractcode(function)
newbytecode = []

for opcode, arg in code.code:
    if opcode in (NONLOCAL_CODES):
        opcode = LOCAL_EQUIVALENT

    newbytecode.append((opcode, arg))

code.code = newbytecode

return code.to_code()
```

It's slightly more complicated than that, but the article provides some great information.

He also recommends not to use it in production. :D

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to declare `build` as global in `wrap`:

```
def configure():
  build()

def wrap(function):
  global build
  def build():
    print 'build'

  function()

wrap(configure)
```

However, I don't really recommend this since it will pollute the namespace.

Comment: Right, I don't want to pollute the namespace. I just want to modify the scope when configure is called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`global`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) statement so that `build()` is defined in the global scope, try the following:

```
def wrap(function):
  global build
  def build():
    print 'build'

  function()
```

Comment: I don't want build() to be in global scope, as that would defeat the purpose of wrapping configure()'s scope.

Comment: You could add `del build` after the `function()` line to remove `build()` from the global namespace.  This is the only way I am aware of to get your code to work without modifying `configure()`.