# Assign variable to local scope of function in Python

Tags: python, lambda

I'd like to assign a variable to the scope of a lambda that is called several times. Each time with a new instance of the variable. How do I do that?

```
f = lambda x: x + var.x - var.y

# Code needed here to prepare f with a new var

result = f(10)
```

In this case it's var I'd like to replace for each invocation without making it a second argument.

Comment: don't use a `lambda`, use a regular function, you shouldn't feel the need to use `lambda`s whenever possible

Comment: In general, if a lambda is complex enough that you have to ask how to contort it to accomplish a task, just use a regular 'def' function. It will result it more readable, maintainable code.

Comment: @jamylak I agree. But lambda or regular function, I'm not sure how the OP wants to accomplish what he's asking. How do you change something in the scope of a function, without using an argument?

Comment: You can replace the lambda with a regular function if that helps. I just need to somehow manipulate the functions local variables/closure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify the local namespace in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142068/how-to-modify-the-local-namespace-in-python) or [How to dynamically modify a function's local namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488296/how-to-dynamically-modify-a-functions-local-namespace) @JonathonReinhart there are a few ways but no clean ones as seen in those links

Comment: @jamylak That's referring to *namespace*. Does that really apply to function-scoped variables?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yes, also OP specified that he can't add another argument to the `lambda` definition so there is no other way

Comment: @jamylak Right. The whole thing is starting to seem absurd :-P

Comment: The lambda is defined externally and out of my control, but I want to provide a scope for the lambda creators. Does that make it make more sense?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variables undefined in the scope of a `lambda` are resolved from the calling scope at the point where it's called.

A slightly simpler example...

```
>>> y = 1
>>> f = lambda x: x + y
>>> f(1)
2
>>> y = 2
>>> f(1)
3
```

...so you just need to set `var` in the calling scope before calling your `lambda`, although this is more commonly used in cases where `y` is 'constant'.

A disassembly of that function reveals...

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (y)
              6 BINARY_ADD
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

If you want to bind `y` to an object at the point of defining the `lambda` (i.e. creating a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)), it's common to see this idiom...

```
>>> y = 1
>>> f = lambda x, y=y: x + y
>>> f(1)
2
>>> y = 2
>>> f(1)
2
```

...whereby changes to `y` after defining the `lambda` have no effect.

A disassembly of that function reveals...

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
              6 BINARY_ADD
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: While this is nifty, and what the OP was asking for, I feel sorry for the poor shmuck that has to maintain this. "Where the hell is `y` coming from in this lambda?!" It may be obvious in this example, but not in a larger project.  Remember the python idiom "explicit over implicit"... I don' think this is explicit.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I agree. I mainly posted this because the other answers implied that it wasn't possible, so I just wanted to demonstrate that it was *possible*. Whether or not it's a *good idea* is subjective. There's probably a better solution for what the OP wants to achieve, but the original question doesn't really contain enough info to make that determination.

Answer (score 1):

`f = functools.partial(lambda var, x: x + var.x - var.y, var)` will give you a function (`f`) of one parameter (`x`) with `var` fixed at the value it was at the point of definition.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the assignment statement in lambda expression, so you'll have to use a regular named function:

```
def f(x):
    global var
    var = x
```

Note the use of the "global" keyword. Without it, Python will assume you want to create a new "var" variable in the local scope of the function.

Comment: Upps. Sorry, assumed you wanted to assign to a variable, not to an object field. The "global" isn't needed in that case (as you're not introducing a new binding).

Comment: I don't consider using a global to be "assign[ing] a variable to the scope of" a function.  That is a globally-scoped variable.

Comment: I am not sure how this helps in my case?

Comment: @JonasKlemming If the variable is in the global scope, changing it externally will change it everywhere, including inside the function. It's a bad idea, but it would work.

Comment: Ah ok, maybe using global is a solution after all.

Comment: Why cant you use a assignment statement in a lambda expression?

Comment: Because, the assignment can only be used as a statement, it is not a valid expression.

Answer (score -1):

Make it another parameter:

```
f = lambda x,var: x + var.x - var.y
result = f(10, var)
```

Lambda or regular function, the only way you can change a variable in the scope of a function is via an argument.

Comment: Thanks, that was my first thought, but I want to avoid a second argument.

Comment: Well then how else can you do it?  How do you possibly control what `var` is for each invocation of `f`?

Comment: In that case yes, re-define the lambda every place you want to use it. Seems silly and convoluted. (aka difficult to understand, maintain, etc.)

Comment: Why *avoid a second argument*? If you want two pieces of data, why obscure that?

Comment: Yes, that would not be an acceptable solution, maybe this is impossible.

Comment: The reason to avoid two arguments is that the second would seldom be used but some cases needs it and I want to keep the lambda as trivial as possible.

Comment: Okay, but when it's not used, what is `var` then? This becomes so complicated. Perhaps you need to provide more information/code to help us understand what *exactly* you're trying to do. I would consider deleting this entire question and starting over.