# Capture variable from for-loop for using later in QPushButton

Tags: python, lambda, scope, pyqt, pylint

**Disclaimer**: I've read other questions like this already (eg. this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314547/cell-var-from-loop-warning-from-pylint)) but didn't find a working solution for me yet (or I just don't understand them :))

When I create a `lambda` inside a for loop accessing data from the scope of the block I get a `pylint` warning (`cell-var-from-loop`) because of the way Python captures work. E.g:

```
for key, value in data.items():
    button = QtGui.QPushButton('show data')
    button.clicked.connect(lambda: show_data(value))
    table_widget.setCellWidget(1, 1, button)
```

There are more questions like this but I still don't now how I systematically solve this issue. I tried to provide default values to the `lambda` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559764/assign-variable-to-local-scope-of-function-in-python):

```
for key, value in data.items():
    button = QtGui.QPushButton('show data')
    button.clicked.connect(lambda v=value: show_data(v))
    table_widget.setCellWidget(1, 1, button)
```

But when I do it like this weird things happen - while `value` ought to be a string in my example `show_data` is being called with a `bool`.

Am I doing something totally wrong? Should this approach work?

Comment: The `clicked` signal sends a `checked` parameter. Use: `button.clicked.connect(lambda chk, v=value: show_data(v))`.

Comment: wow :) can you please turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [clicked signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) sends a *checked* parameter. So try:

```
button.clicked.connect(lambda checked, v=value: show_data(v))
```