# Set multiple similar variables in Python

Tags: python, variables, rss, set

How would I clean up the following code and make it look better?

I wonder if there is a way to set all these variables and values in an easier and shorter version. What would be an example of doing so? :-)

```
import feedparser
import memcache
import sys

mc = memcache.Client(["127.0.0.1:11211"])
rss = feedparser.parse('http://example.com/example.rss')
song0 = rss.entries[0].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")
song1 = rss.entries[1].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")
song2 = rss.entries[2].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")
song3 = rss.entries[3].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")
song4 = rss.entries[4].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")
song5 = rss.entries[5].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")
song6 = rss.entries[6].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")
song7 = rss.entries[7].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")
song8 = rss.entries[8].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")
song9 = rss.entries[9].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")

mc.set("track0", song0);
mc.set("track1", song1);
mc.set("track2", song2);
mc.set("track3", song3);
mc.set("track4", song4);
mc.set("track5", song5);
mc.set("track6", song6);
mc.set("track7", song7);
mc.set("track8", song8);
mc.set("track9", song9);
```

Comment: This is not really deserving of a question so don't be too surprised if it is closed.  However, rss must be an iterable so for item in iterable:  do_something  it could be done in one line with a list comprehension

Comment: What I mainly was looking for and failed was the function list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `enumerate()` with `rss.entries` would free you from the burden of manually maintaining an index. Best of all, it'd work regardless of the length of `rss.entries`.

```
import feedparser
import memcache
import sys

mc = memcache.Client(["127.0.0.1:11211"])
rss = feedparser.parse('http://example.com/example.rss')

song = []
for i, entry in enumerate(rss.entries):
    title = entry.title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")
    song.append(title)
    mc.set("track%d" % i, title)
```

Comment: I had to initialize the list with song = {} otherwise I get IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You ended up using dictionary, not list (`{}` stands for dictionary literal). Updated the code to work correctly for list.

Answer (score 2):

You have 10 variables with similar names only differing by a number. It's a sure sign that what you really want to use is a list:

```
songs = [i.title.encode("latin-1", "replace").replace("?" , "-") for i in rss.entries]
```

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest (thus best) way:

```
import feedparser
import memcache
import sys

mc = memcache.Client(["127.0.0.1:11211"])
rss = feedparser.parse('http://example.com/example.rss')
songs = [] # Initialize “songs” to the empty list
for i in range(0, 10):
    # Add items in “songs”
    songs.append(rss.entries[i].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-"))

for (i, song) in enumerate(songs): # This is equivalent to “for i in range(0, len(songs)+1):” and “song = songs[i]”
    mc.set("track%i" % i, song);
```

If you really want to keep songs in different variables (I'm almost sure you don't actually want to; more over it is not recommended to use it (see the comments on this question)):

```
import feedparser
import memcache
import sys

mc = memcache.Client(["127.0.0.1:11211"])
rss = feedparser.parse('http://example.com/example.rss')
for i in range(0, 10):
    locals()['song%i' % i] = rss.entries[0].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")

for i in range(0, 10):
    mc.set("track%i" % i, locals()['song%i' % i]);
```

Comment: have you actually tried the second solution (using `locals()`)? i'm pretty sure that doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me on a small example (`locals()['spam'] = 'egg'` and `print(locals()['spam'])`)

Comment: please look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488296/how-to-dynamically-modify-a-functions-local-namespace?lq=1 even if it works, the doc explicitly warns against it as unsafe.

Comment: note that the way you have used `locals()`, it could be any dictionary - wouldn't specifically have to be the locals, since you get the value out also by dereferencing `locals()` in your example. in fact, that's how it works - if you try to access the variable `song1` directly, it won't work - it's not really added to the local namespace. but `locals()` returns the same dictionary every time, so you see the addition later.

Comment: I just tested, accessing `spam` after doing `locals()['spam'] = 'egg'`) works. (But I agree the doc says we should not rely on it)

Comment: When I try this I get IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

```
import feedparser
import memcache
import sys

mc = memcache.Client(["127.0.0.1:11211"])
rss = feedparser.parse('http://example.com/example.rss')
song=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    song[i] = rss.entries[i].title.encode('latin-1', 'replace').replace("?" , "-")
    mc.set("track"+str(i), song[i]);
```